# Do we really need finite variances $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ in the definition of covariance $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

You know that covariance of jointly distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$ is $$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm{E}[XY] - \mathrm{E}[X] \mathrm{E}[Y].$$

It is clear that we should require finiteness of $\mathrm{E}[XY], \mathrm{E}[X]$ and $\mathrm{E}[Y]$. In particular, this requirement will be met (by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) if $\mathrm{Var}(X) < \infty$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y) < \infty$.

There are cases when $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) < \infty$ but $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ are infinite (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804229/covariance-of-random-variables-which-dont-have-variances) for example). Also I think $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ can be finite if only one of the variances is infinite.

But Wikipedia requires finiteness of variances $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ directly in its [covariance definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition). Also in the definition of cross-covariance matrix $$\mathrm{Cov}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}) = \mathrm{E}[(\mathbf{X} - \mathrm{E}[\mathbf{X}])(\mathbf{Y} - \mathrm{E}[\mathbf{Y}])^T]$$
wikipedia again [requires finiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance#Statistics) of variances of all elements of the random vectors $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$.

Firstly when I saw the covariance definition in Wikipedia I thought it was a mistake to require finiteness of variances $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$. But when I saw this requirement again in the cross-covariance matrix definition I started to doubt.

What do ou think about it? 
Do we really need finite variances $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ in the definition of covariance $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$? 
And do we really need finite variances of all elements of the random vectors $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ in the definition of cross-covariance matrix $\mathrm{Cov}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})$?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent with finite first moment but infinite second moment. Then $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]$ so $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question: I must not be awake yet.

Comment: Moreover, random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not required to have joint distribution. They only need to be defined on the same sample space.  So Wikipedia's definition of the covariance has two mistakes!